# Link click event blocked by parent mousedown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link inside a header such as this

```
<table id="mytable" border=1>
<thead>
  <th id='myHeader'><a href="#" class="sortHeader">HelloWorld</a></th>
</thead>
</table>
```

And some sample javascript, hooking up a click event on the link, and a mousemove event on the table header element.

```
var randomFunction = function(event, id){
    alert('header was moved');
}

$('#mytable').on('click', '.sortHeader', function(evt){
    alert('header was clicked')
});

var header = document.getElementById('myHeader');
header.addEventListener('mousedown', randomFunction);
```

Unfortunately, when I add the mousedown, the click event no longer is set off by a click.  I've checked the events in google developer tools, and they're both there.  How do I get the click event to fire?

Here's a full jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nickwinters/xLz8agy0/1/

Comment: I tried your fiddle - both alerts are displayed, so the click handler was called. What else are you doing in your real mouse down handler? If you are moving elements as implied by the alert message then that could prevent a click event. As an aside, why are you only using jQuery for one of the two event handlers?

Comment: Use console.log to test these instead of alert. With console.log this isn't reproduced. https://jsfiddle.net/xLz8agy0/2/

Comment: You're correct.  Console.log works.  Ok, so something is still wrong with my larger code.  I'll have to keep trying and reproduce the problem in jsfiddle.

Comment: Turns out my real problem was I was moving the columns, so the original link was no longer there.  This is for drag and drop columns in a table.  I was moving them, even if it was just putting the td's back in their own place.  I've added a quick check, if origin and destination are the same, don't move them.  Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `console.log();` instead of `alert()`.

Because on mouse down your calling the `alert()` function which interrupts with `mouseup` in click function, hence `alert` in the click function is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of having two click events, one inside the other. By using the stop propagation function on the click event you can stop the event from bubbling up and triggering the other event.

```
'use strict';

let outer = document.querySelector('.outer');
let inner = document.querySelector('.inner');

let outerClick = (e) => {
  alert('outer clicked');
}

let innerClick = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('inner clicked');
}

outer.addEventListener('click', outerClick);
inner.addEventListener('click', innerClick);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pz47f1kx/

Comment: But the question is about how to get a mouse down and a click to both happen, not about how to stop propagation. This is the opposite of what they want to do.